# What is the ideal way to JSON.stringify in Terraform?

Tags: json, terraform, hcl

I'm working on my first Terraform project and I'm looking for the best way to stringify a JSON object. The resource I'm defining has a parameter that expects a JSON string. JSON structure is:

```
  "document": {
    "tag": "String Title",
    "response": "There's a string response and perhaps a price like $[XX.XX]."
  }
}
```

I don't think jsonencode or jsondecode do this. I could stringify them in advance but that isn't scalable in this case. I wasn't sure if I could do this with JavaScript or another language alongside Terraform, or if there's a function in HCL that will do it.

Comment: That is exactly what `jsonencode` does. Why are you saying `jsonencode` won't work for you?

Comment: @MarkB The documentation and example there doesn't look like it would: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode

Comment: I guess you need to show more of what you think your Terraform should look like, and what you want the final outcome to be. The example in the link at https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode looks exactly like what you need. Terraform doesn't have the concept of JSON objects at all. Terraform isn't JavaScript. Terraform is written in HCL and has HCL objects. The `jsonencode` function can take an HCL object defined in your Terraform code and convert it into a JSON string for resources that expect JSON strings.

Answer (score 1):

`jsonencode` in Terraform is exactly equivalent to `JSON.stringify` with only one argument in JavaScript.

For example, if you need to assign a string containing a JSON object to an argument called `something_json`, you could do that like this:

```
  something_json = jsonencode({
    document = {
      tag      = "String Title"
      response = "There's a string response and perhaps a price like $[XX.XX]."
    }
  })
```

The above would set `something_json` to a minified version of the following JSON:

```
{
  "document": {
    "tag": "String Title",
    "response": "There's a string response and perhaps a price like $[XX.XX]."
  }
}
```

Terraform does not have an equivalent of the optional `replacer` and `space` arguments in JavaScript's `JSON.stringify`:

- An equivalent of `replacer` isn't needed in Terraform because all possible values in the Terraform language have a defined JSON equivalent as described in the table in [the `jsonencode` documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/jsonencode).
- `space` is for generating non-minified JSON; Terraform does not offer any way to do this because it is focused on generating JSON for machine consumption and so prefers to generate the most compact representation possible.

Comment: Regarding using Terraform and JSON outside the (needlessly narrow) assumption made by its developers: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21755 (tl;dr; as usually, you will never have need to do anything we haven't already thought of so why are you asking?)